# Does the impeachment of Donald Trump render his future pardons void?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, trump-impeachment, pardon

Usually near the end of their terms, U.S. Presidents grant pardons. It is expected from current U.S. President Donal Trump that he will grant several pardons in the following week. Granting pardons is a presidential power as written in the U.S. Constitution (article 2, section 2, clause 1):

> The President ... shall have Power to grant Reprieves and Pardons for Offenses against the United States, **except in Cases of impeachment**.

But it happens that Trump is now impeached since January 13<sup>th</sup>, and he will very likely still be impeached by the end of his term on January 20<sup>th</sup>.

Does the emphasized exception mean that any pardon that Trump would grant between his impeachment on January 13<sup>th</sup> and the end of his term on January 20<sup>th</sup> are void?

Comment: Your quoted line means that pardons do not grant immunity against impeachment. It doesn’t mean that an impeached President cannot give pardons.

Comment: @Panda That's what I'm asking to clarify as for a non-native English speaker, this sentence might be understood in several ways.

Comment: @Panda No : because that answer provides clues for past pardons. I'm asking for pardons between an impeachment and the end of the impeachment (or term, whichever comes first).

Comment: A President can exercise all his powers, including pardons, unless he is convicted by the Senate and removed from office. Impeachment, without conviction, has no effect on a President’s powers.

Comment: @Panda That's the correct answer; you should post it as an answer!

Comment: @DanScally I think it’s somewhat similar to the 2nd answer at [Will Trump's pardons remain valid if he is impeached?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30361/will-trumps-pardons-remain-valid-if-he-is-impeached).

Comment: @Panda Oh, yes I agree. Sorry; hadn't read the link for some reason